# change field name when serializing object

Tags: java, json, serialization, boon

I have this class:

```
import org.boon.json.annotations.SerializedName;

public class QueuedMessage {

    @SerializedName("message_id")
    String id;

    @SerializedName("message")
    String msg;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

I create an object and serialize it, but field names are not changed

```
    QueuedMessage qm = new QueuedMessage();
    qm.setId("1");
    qm.setMsg("hi");
    String js1 = json.toJson(qm);
```

I expect js1 variable be something like: {"message_id":"1","message":"hi"}
but it is: {"id":"1","msg":"hi","id":"1","msg":"hi"}

Comment: Maybe try to use @JsonProperty

Comment: it doesn't work too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the `JsonFactory` to use annotations:

```
ObjectMapper json = JsonFactory.createUseAnnotations(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the `Boon` but this is how you can use `Gson` to serialize the `Object`, there may be some issue with the import of `String` or `SerializedName`, Kindly check that. This example runs as the output shown. the code is also available on [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/blob/master/src/stack/overflow/test/two/TestDriveOne.java)
.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 14-02-2016.
 */
public class TestDriveOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueuedMessage queuedMessage = new QueuedMessage("123", "Hello World");
        System.out.println((new Gson()).toJson(queuedMessage));
    }


}

class QueuedMessage {

    @SerializedName("message_id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String msg;

    public QueuedMessage() {
    }

    public QueuedMessage(String id, String msg) {
        this.id = id;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

.

> Output

```
{
  "message_id": "123",
  "message": "Hello World"
}
```